# Frame-perfect audio cutting using ffmpeg filter graphs and frame filtering

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I'm curious, is it possible to do frame-perfect audio cutting using ffmpeg's complex filter graphs + frame filtering `aselect` functionality?

I've tried a bunch of other approaches (using `-segment_times` and `-ss`/`-t`) - they worked but were only `~0.02sec` accurate, just for reference:

- `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -ar 48000 test.wav`
- `ffmpeg -y -i test.wav -f segment -segment_times "1.55,2.00" -segment_list_type csv -segment_list output.csv test%04d.opus`
- `ffmpeg -y -i test.wav -ss 0.00 -t 1.55 test0000.opus -ss 2.00 -t 1.00 test0001.opus`

My filter-based attempts:

- `ffmpeg -y -i test.wav -ar 48000 -af "aselect=between(samples_n\,100\,16100)" test0000.opus` as an example but this produces a 5-second long `test0000.opus` instead of a 0.25-second one
- `ffmpeg -y -i test.wav -ar 48000 -af "aselect=between(t\,0.0\,1.55)" test0000.opus` kind of works, but still gives a 1.57-second audio instead of 1.55-second one.

Can this be done in principle using frame filtering? Am I missing something in these commands above? If the filter-based approach is not more accurate, I will fall back to my initial attempts.

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue as https://video.stackexchange.com/q/26451/

Comment: I think the linked issue is about generation of files of specific duration while here I'm inquiring about cutting from an input PCM with sample-perfect provided boundaries (I realize that some padding may appear during encoding to opus, but I care that input cutpoints are as sample-precise as possible)